# Why is extern "C" working only inside the file to be included, not when wrapped around the #include directive

Tags: c++, objective-c, include, objective-c++, extern

I'm including a C file called "AniUtils.h" in an Objective C++ class. I understand that I need to use 'extern "C"' if I'm going to include a C file in a C++ file. What's confusing me is that wrapping the include directive in an extern C doesn't seem to work, while putting extern C in the body of the file does.

So, wrapping the include directive doesn't work.

```
extern "C" {
    #include "AniUtils.h"
}
```

However, doing it this way works fine:

```
// AniUtils.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// body of included file

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Why does the second approach work but not the first?

Comment: are you able to compare the pre-processed source files?

Comment: Post the linker errors.  The second method is preferable in almost all cases in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If your `AniUtils.h` file is included by any other **Objective-C** classes (e.g., .m files; not Objective-C++, .mm files), then the first way you've implemented the `extern C` statement will cause errors.

For example, here is a plain Objective C class that will be importing the problematic `AniUtils.h` Objective-C++ class. Note that because these files are `WowClass.h` & `WowClass.m`, these files will be processed as plain Objective-C:

WowClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AniUtils.h"

@interface WowClass : NSObject {

}

@end
```

WowClass.m:

```
#import "WowClass.h"

@implementation
 .....
@end
```

Now, if your `AniUtils.h` is defined in the first manner, you'll get errors when trying to process the `WowClass.m` file, which includes the `extern C` statement, as plain Objective-C. Instead, you need to conditionalize the `extern C` statement in `AniUtils.h`:

```
// AniUtils.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// body of included file

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Of course, an alternative would be to simply rename `WowClass.m` to `WowClass.mm` so that the `WowClass` interface and implementation files are always processed as Objective-C++, but that kind of misses the point.

Comment: NSGod, thanks for the reply. I think you may have misunderstood though. AniUtils.h is not an Objective-C class it's just a collection of simple C functions.

Comment: @morgancodes: I wasn't assuming that AniUtils.h was an Obj-C class at all; more that AniUtils.h was paired with come AniUtils.c file that had C functions like you're suggesting. I will try to revise the answer to make it more clear, but basically, by not conditionalizing that `extern "C"` statement, it is in fact **you** who are making the assumption that every single implementation source code file (.c, .cpp, .m, .mm) that includes `AniUtils.h` will be either C++, or Objective-C++. Unless you conditionalize that extern C, you can only have AniUtils.cpp, not AniUtils.c, etc.

Comment: NSGod, thanks for your time. I understand that if I use extern C inside the AniUtils.h file I need to conditionalize it, because it may be included by non-C++ files. What I don't understand is why I can't simply wrap my include directive in extern C, as in the first code snippet in my original post. I had thought that the two would be basically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it should work. Are you sure that `AniUtils.h` is compiled wit a C compiler and not with a C++ one?
There is a really detailed descrption of the whole problematic, take a look here, perhaps it will help you.

http://de.w3support.net/index.php?db=so&id=67894

Comment: It would *have to* be compiled with a C++ compiler, the first fragment is not valid C code, the second has conditional compilation to make it work with either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including AniUtils.h in the .cpp file as well? In the second case it will see the extern "C" as well, but not in the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You might have AniUtils.h included in another file as well.